# CloudsimSDN ERROR:could not find or load main class org.cloudbus.cloudsim.sdn.example

Tags: java, cmd, cloud, sdn, cloudsim

I wanted to run SDNExample of CloudSimSDN with CMD. First I downloaded `cloudsim.4.0` then I put it in the directory cloudsimsdn-2.0.1-beta. Then I installed mvn with code `mvn clean install` in cmd.
mvn with some warning was run. When I enter

```
java -cp cloudsimsdn-1.0-with-dependencies.jar org.cloudbus.cloudsim.sdn.example.SDNExample MFF ../dataset-energy/energy-physical.json ../dataset-energy/energy-virtual.json ../dataset-energy/energy-workload.csv > results.out
```

`ERROR:could not find or load main class org.cloudbus.cloudsim.sdn.example.SDNExample`

According to the instructions on the github site 
https://github.com/Cloudslab/cloudsimsdn/tree/v2.0.1-beta

Comment: Please try to be more elaborative by adding some examples/code snippet of what you are trying to do.

Comment: i try to run SimpleExample in CloudsimSDN simulator with netbeans in cmd.this code that I enter in cmd is ""java -cp cloudsimsdn-1.0-with-dependencies.jar org.cloudbus.cloudsim.sdn.example.SDNExample MFF ../dataset-energy/energy-physical.json ../dataset-energy/energy-virtual.json ../dataset-energy/energy-workload.csv > results.out" this code in in GitHub but it does not work for me and I dont know the reason of it

Comment: Update your post with the steps you tried and the github link which you are referring.